# Running Java gives "Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"

Tags: java, scala

After years of working OK, I'm suddenly getting this message when trying to start the JVM:

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

I tried uninstalling, and got a message saying a DLL was missing (unspecified)
Tried re-installing, all to no avail.

At the same time, when trying to start Scala I get:

```
\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe was unexpected at this time.
```

Checked `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%path%` - both OK

Can anyone help?

Comment: Looks like your JVM got corrupt, or your PATH is polluted. The JVM you think you are running might not be the JVM you should be running. try running java -version to find out if it is 1.6.0_xx.

Comment: How is this related to Scala?

Comment: I can't even do java -version without getting the message!

Comment: It's related to scala in that scala fails too.  Both occurred at the same time.

Comment: here is what i've found in google. Maybe it will help: [link](http://www.rune-server.org/runescape-development/rs2-server/help/239746-weird-thing-w-java-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: Seems like the same problem, but I don't know what the fix was.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Might be a slightly different cause, but that second issue occurs for me in scala 2.9.0.1 on Win7 (x64), though scala-2.9.1.final has already resolved this issue mentioned here:

```
\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe was unexpected at this time.
```

My `%JAVA_HOME%` set to a path like this: `c:\program files`**(x86)**`\Java\jdk...`

Note the space and the parentheses.

If you change line 24 in `%SCALA_HOME%\bin\scala.bat` from:

```
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set _JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
```

to

```
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
```

It works fine. Note the quotes around the set command parameters, this will properly enclose any spaces and 'special' characters (eg: spaces and parentheses) in the variable's value.

Hope this helps someone else searching for an answer.

Comment: +1, but same treatment should be applied also to the file: %SCALA_HOME%\bin\scalac.bat

Comment: thanks! in my case, I renamed the Windows partition where Java was installed. Reverting that change fixed it.

Answer (score 93):

I checked my environment variables - JAVA_HOME & PATH and they all refer to C:\java. So this was bit frustrating. After sometime I found that the default installation also copied java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe to C:\Windows\System32 (i.e. uninstall of JRE didn't go well). I just removed them and voila, I'm back on track. That annoying error is no longer popping.

This works for me

**So, If exists, remove java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from System32**

Comment: Why Oracle/Sun ever decided to do this and not fix the uninstaller is beyond me. Thank you.

Comment: Just removed the whole folder C:/Windows/jre which allowed the proper java exe farther down the path to be the used. No idea what installed java into my windows dir and put it on the path though :|

Comment: My situation: Eclipse stopped launching. Proguard wouldn't load due to a missing jvm.cfg file. Removed windows/jre, and the exe files mentioned above. Solved my issue. This just happened seemingly randomly over the last week. No explanation for it.

Comment: It worked after I removed java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from C:\Windows\System32. Thanks @Full-Stack Software Engineer. You saved my time.

Answer (score 47):

put  %JAVA_HOME%\bin   at the begin of PATH.

Comment: Got the same problem on Windows although my PATH and JAVA_HOME was OK. Moving the %JAVA_HOME% to the beginning of the PATH solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Despite doing this, I was getting the error.  What I didn't notice was when I opened a CMD prompt, it would default to C:\Windows\System32, which contained the troublesome java install.  Changing out to any other directory would make Java work just fine with the JDK I wanted on the path.

Answer (score 10):

I had a slight different solution to this problem. my PATH and JAVA_HOME were pointing to JDK12 in

```
C:\Program Files\Java
```

but execution of the command:

```
Java -version
```

gave the error:

```
Error: could not open `C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jre1.8.0_212\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

I had to delete a folder of executables (Java.exe, javaw.exe etc.) in a different directory than System32, as other answers here and blog posts have suggested. Instead I found the problem lied with executables found in:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle
```

as there was nothing Java related in

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

If you're having this issue and nothing is in System32, check this "common files" directory mentioned above for an oracle directory and delete it.

After, your PATH references should work fine!

Comment: Check at the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" as well sometimes, you might have installed some program which silently installed Java.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem: I have a 64 bit Windows and when I typed "java -version" in CMD-Console i received the same Error message.
Try to start a 64bit-cmd(C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe) and you will see, it works there ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

I took a back up of the files in it and removed those files from there. Then I opened a new cmd prompt and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

If this was working before, it means the `PATH` isn't correct anymore.

That can happen when the `PATH` becomes too long and gets truncated.
All posts (like [this one](http://www.rune-server.org/runescape-development/rs2-server/help/284879-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64-jvm-cfg.html)) suggest [updating the `PATH`](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), which you can test first in a separate DOS session, by setting a minimal path and see if java works again there.

---

Finally the [OP Highland Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559426/highland-mark) concludes:

> Finally fixed by uninstalling java, removing all references to it from the registry, and then re-installing.

scary ;)

Comment: Thanks. Still I can't sort it. With minimal path (path = %JAVA_HOME%\bin) it works - as you say, however, I can't see the problem in the actual path which is "...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;..." which contains the same thing.

Comment: Finally managed to remove old versions of JRE using JavaRA & MSICUU2.exe, reloaded latest version, but still the same message.

Comment: @Highland: if this works with a minimal path but not with a full path, that means `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` isn't the issue. Some other element in the `PATH` causes the runtime to fail. Could you try with a `PATH` you would build, one element at a time, to see when java stop launching?

Comment: Thanks VonC - that gives me something to work on.  I'll report back.

Comment: It wasn't in the path. Finally fixed by uninstalling java, removing all references to it from the registry, and then re-installing.  None the wiser, but back working again.  Thanks all.

Comment: @Highland: ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer. At least you got it working again.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I will share how I resolved the same issue "Error Could not open lib\amd64\jvm.cfg". I found the Java run time Jre7 is missing amd64 folder under lib. However, I have 1.7.0_25 JDK which is having jre folder and also having amd64.

I moved the original contents of jre7 folder to a backup file and copied everything from 1.7.0_25\jre.

Now I am not getting this error anymore and able to proceed with scene builder.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 7 install on my work PC broke after a patch was forced out to us, giving this error any time you tried to run a Java program.  Somehow the entire 'lib' subdirectory of the Java 7 install vanished!  Might have been related to having both Java 6 and Java 7 installed -- the 'jre6' directory still had everything there.

In any case, I fixed it by uninstalling both Java 6 and Java 7 and reinstalling just Java 7.  But if the file it's complaining about is actually there, then you're likely having a path issue as described in some of the other answers here.

Comment: except in my case reinstalling the JRE did not replace the missing `lib` folder :(

Comment: Ah ... I reinstalled the 64-bit JRE, but it turns out there was also a 32-bit JRE installed.  I uninstalled both -- they were a couple of patchlevels behind anyway -- then reinstalled the 64-bit JRE (only) and now everything is copacetic.

Answer (score 2):

Had suddenly the same Problem, from one day to another eclipse said

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:/JDK/bin/client/jvm.dll"`.
```

after trying to run java on the console

```
Error: could not open `C:\WINDOWS\jre\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

now i just deleted the whole directory

```
C:\WINDOWS\jre
```

and everything worked again... i don't know there this jre came from, i hope it was not a virus

Answer (score 1):

- I had a similar problem (trying to start a Jenkins slave agent on Windows) on `Windows 2008R2`, `Java 1.7.0_15`
- I had two situations that contributed to the problem and that changing both of them fixed it:

  1) Installing `Java` in a `unix`-compatible path (changing from `c:\Program Files\... to c:\Software\...`); I don't think this directly affected the problem described in this thread, but noting the change;

  2) Running `Java` not through a shortcut. It originally failed with a shortcut, but `re-running` from the direct executable (`C:\Software\Java...\bin\java`) worked.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is using shortpath in windows:

1. open windows command console using cmd.exe
2. goto `c:\`
3. type command> `dir program* /x`
4. it should display as short path like: `PROGRA~2`
5. so `C:\PROGRA~2` is same as `C:\Program Files (x86)`
6. in your `JAVA_HOME` replace path to :
   `C:\PROGRA~2\Java\jre7`

This should work in windows 64 environment as it worked for me in win7 64bit version.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the java installation path from `c:\Program Files (x86)\java` to another folder like `c:\java\jdk1.7` and updated the `%Java_HOME%` and path values accordingly,it worked.

example

```
%JAVA_HOME% = C:\java\JDK1.7

path-C:\java\JDK1.7\bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in **Eclipse** and I fixed it by changing the **JRE** from 64 bit to **32 bit**:

Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Add... > Next > Directory > select "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65" instead of "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60"

Comment: This issue occurred to me while installing eclipse.
I was installing eclipse after JAVA update where my earlier version was 1.8.0_60 and the newer version was 1.8.0_191 which i guess is changed while installing update so i changed folder name to earlier i.e. 1.8.0_60 . So the issue is with post install script of JAVA update i guess
@ time of Update installation both names should be changed by install which is not the case. i.e. minor change is remaining after post install of java update.

Answer (score 1):

I kept **variable name** as "Path" but it did not work **after changing it to** "**PATH**"
started working for me.

**variable name:** PATH

**variable value:** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin

this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling java didn't help me. But the trick to put the JAVA_HOME variable at the beginning of the env-vars. The problem occoured after an upgrade from jdk1.7.0_11 to jdk1.7.0_13

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after updating your java. The best way to solve this problem is just go to your `c:/ProgramFiles/Java` folder. There you will find two jre folders one is as jre.your version and other with exactly like jdk folder. Try to remove jre.1.your version folder. There you go your problem is solved. Hope this might help. It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Typically it because of upgrading JRE.

It changes symlinks into C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\

Intall JDK - it will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Looking @ it the issue of post install script is there and getting propagated since I am using update jdk8 1.8.0_191 since issue occurred with me after installing update of java and which was happened automatically.

```
Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

This will be never ending in this case and need to do workaround like changing path's manually.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the jars under system32 for windows.
Delete the jars under C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle

Edit the environment variable set JAVA_HOME and SET PATH to bin

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by deleting the Oracle folder from Program Data. And also delete the oracle java path associated with that folder from environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

It wasn't in the path. Finally fixed by uninstalling java, removing all references to it from the registry, and then re-installing. None the wiser, but back working again. Thanks all @Highland Mark- Can you tell me the process to removing references from registry. I tried all possible way people mentioned here, nothing worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you have downloaded several Jdks you have to delete all except of the JDK you want to use!