# Cordova - Unable to access jarfile c:\...\cordova\appinfo.jar

Tags: android, cordova

I've created a cordova project with the following commands:

```
cordova create -d hello
cd hello
cordova -d platform add android
cordova -d build
cordova -d emulate android
```

and this last command output is:

> Failed to get application name from appinfo.jar + AndroidManifest:
>   Output: Error: Unable to access jarfile
>   C:\hello\platforms\android\cordova\appinfo.jar

Any clues why this is happening?

**Cordova -v** : 3.09
**ant -version**: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
**java -version**: 
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

SO: Windows 7 64-bits

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error - turned out there was an incorrect version of Java in the System32 folder (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086496/345078)).

Once I removed the incorrect files I was able to install on the emulator.