# how to change default java path

Tags: java

How can I change default java? Here is my java home directory;

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05;

JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre;
```

I also added `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05"` directory to path variable.But the problem is  when I type `java -version` from console the output is;

```
Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No it doesn't

Comment: Not sure it's the same thing, but maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I also added "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05" directory to path
>   variable."

Instead you should add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` and `%JRE_HOME%\bin` to your path. See if that clears up the problem.

*Note* that you'll need to open a new command window before the changes will apply

Answer (score 0):

Try these two things

```
REM First set JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05
REM Add to the PATH.
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: He's most likely working with the environment variables panel.  This solution will only last so long as his current command window is open, and then only within that command window, a second one will not see the changes