# Eclipse: Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Windows\system32\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jvm, installation

Couple days ago, I was happily coding away on my IDE, Eclipse. However, after attempting to boot it up today, i get the error in the title you see.

Symptoms:

- Attempting to boot up eclipse results in an error: 'Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Windows\system32\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"'
 - Attempting to use 'java -version' results in an error: 'Error: could not open 'C:\Windows\jre\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
 - However, if I open cmd in the jre OR jdk folder, it allows me to check the version and use java as normal.

What i've done:

- double checked windows, eclipse, and jre/jdk bit versions, all 64 bit.
 - reinstalled eclipse and jre/jdk, doublechecking that I'm installing 64 bit versions
 - set my -vm argument to the correct jdk
 - set the PATH to my current JDK bin folder
 - doublechecked registry entries for something pointing towards the system32 folder, everything is pointing at the correct locations.

I'm really not sure what to do here :\ I don't remember making any changes, updating java, or modifying anything that should have caused any of these problems since the last time I had boot up eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086496/1340219)

For whatever reason, the java install dumped the java/javaw/javaws.exe's into system32 and it was trying to run the VM out of sys32.