# Java not working

Tags: java

I recently switched from Java 7 to Java 6 and now Java is not working for me at all. I have made sure Java 7 was completely uninstalled, and have correctly installed Java 6 (it appears in my control panel and everything). I have made sure my environment variables are pointing to the correct locations as well.

For some reason though Java is just completely broken. Typing in java version into the command prompt reveals this

**Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'**

I have tried scouring the registry for any traces of Java 7, but I cannot find anything. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

### edit

Now java version reveals

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: version
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: version
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: version.  Program will exit.
```

### Edit 2

Ok....sorry. I was typing java version instead of java -version.

Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Java gives "Error: could not open \`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64)

Comment: Fix your system environment variables. `%PATH%` and `%JAVA_HOME%`.

Comment: have a look at http://jaykhimani.blogspot.de/2012/09/error-could-not-open-cprogram.html

Comment: the error points to a java 7 folder (jre7) , this suggests that your environment vars need to be updated

Comment: @Orel Eraki This has nothing to do with Scala

Comment: My environment variables have been updated

Comment: @Thomas Junk I deleted those files like that link said to,  now when I type java into the command prompt I get 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: Ok I made an edit to the post as to what is happening now

Comment: You're probably executing 'java version' and not 'java -version'.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how did you uninstall Java 7? Did you just delete the folders or did you use the actual proper uninstaller?

Comment: @Gimby I did both. Spent like an hour searching for every java related file I could find on my computer.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: Seriously this community is ridiculous. People expect you to be an expert on everything before posting a question.

Comment: Yeah well I can understand the downvoting, this is a site for programming questions, not for computer tech support. You're better off asking these kinds of questions in a forum, not on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to start -> rightclick on computer -> `properties`
Then, in the left pane, click on Advanced system settings.
Inside the tab `advanced`, click on `Environment Variables...` right at the bottom of the window.
In the upper pane, click on `PATH` -> `edit` and add the following line to the text to the popup that shows up:

```
;%PATH_TO_JAVA%\bin
```

Where you replace `%PATH_TO_JAVA%` with the path to your java installation (including `jre6` or something like that)

Don't forget the semicollumn if there is already something in the box, also, dont delete that, just put your path right behind that, no spaces.