# Scala compiler with space in classpath

Tags: scala, scalac

`scalac D:\temp\main.scala` works

`scalac "D:\Programming\Java works\my project\main.scala"` returns this error:

> works\my was unexpected at this time

I think the problem is caused by spaces in path.
How can I resolve this problem (I would not remove spaces in path)?

Scala 2.11.6 (last version) on Windows 7 x64

Comment: as quick solution you can use short path, to find out path check http://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file

Comment: Personally, I would suggest not using spaces in your directory/file names.  That said, it may be something with scala expecting a string that's escaped for a unix-type filesystem.  Does adding a backslash in the string before the space help at all?

Comment: A bit more looking around found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64.  It may just be an error in the batch file that runs scala in Windows.