# Jar files no longer running

Tags: java, jar, runtime

i have been working in netbeans on my own various projects and for some reason i can no longer run java jars. At first it kept saying that it opened with an unknown application, so i set it manually to my installation of java 8.111 but now it still isnt working.

when launching a jar from the command line it gives me this:
Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_65\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

I thought about changing my classpath but im not sure what i should change it to or even if that is the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Java gives "Error: could not open \`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up figuring out it was trying to launch an old version of java (_65) even though that  was incorrect. i tried to get it to use the latest one but to no avail. evenually a reinstall of java fixed the problem