# Error while attempting to install scala SDK in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

When I try to install the Scala SDK, I get the following

```
error: sbt-based downloader
Error: could not open `E:\Java\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'.
```

How can I fix this issue?

I have tried reinstalling both the Java JDK and IntelliJ Idea. My JAVA_HOME is set to the .exe file of the jdk in my downloads folder.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64 ?  Usually, JAVA_HOME is assigned to Java installation directory, not linked to the .exe of JDK. For example, JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

Comment: JAVA_HOME is set to the .exe file

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME should be set to the same directory that contains the "bin" folder in JDK install directory.