# java -version: Error: could not open `D:\software\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Tags: java

I'm checking my Java version in my console, type java, and I get this error

```
Active code page: 65001
~> java -v
Error: could not open `D:\software\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

First,

```
cd d:   
ls
```

Confusingly, I don't even have a directory named

```
`D:\software`
```

Second, I checked my JAVA_HOME & PATH in my user environment:

JAVA_HOME :

```
C:\Users\gmrhh\.sdkman\candidates\java\current
```

PATH :

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin;
```

seems it has nothing to do with the directory:

```
D:\software\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg
```

I've searched
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036462/running-java-gives-error-could-not-open-c-program-files-java-jre6-lib-amd64](https://stackoverflow.com)

Additionally:

OS:Windows 11

jdk JAVA_HOME point to:zulu-1.8

But still don't have a clue, can anyone help?

Comment: In the Windows OS Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs & Features is Java and JDK listed? You will be able to uninstall and install again - if you want to. For uninstall follow these instructions from https://www.java.com/en/uninstall/ .

Comment: Also, include the following in your question post: the OS and Java versions you are working with.

Comment: cool, really help this JavaUninstall Tool the exe, now it works, amazing bro

Comment: C:\Users\gmrhh>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-win64) (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.72.0.17-CA-win64) (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)

C:\Users\gmrhh>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Users\gmrhh\.sdkman\candidates\java\current It seems that the uninstall tool automatically uninstall a jdk which I don't know its path but it's related to may be my java_home

Comment: Add details printed by `where java` which should pinpoint your path issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try deleting java related exe files from paths c:\windows & c:\windows\system32 & C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath and retry java command in new command prompt
2. If it not works, please try deleting java related exe files from above paths and try uninstalling and re-installing java

Comment: I’ve deleted all my .exe files in C: and all my jdks, but when I type java in the command prompt, I get the same mistake:Error: could not open `D:\software\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Comment: can you pls try uninstalling and re-installing java once again.

Comment: 3Q，i've install JavaUninstall to delete a hidden jdk version, and it works

Comment: So, somewhere the java installer is pointed to D:\ path earlier, when you do uninstalling and installling all the older java installation files were removed properly and hence there are no issues. thanks for update.